# Delphi XE6 and Android Ping

Tags: android, delphi, ping, indy, delphi-xe6

I want to ping to a server with indy component TidIcmpClient in Android plattform but the debugger stops the code with a "Socket Error #1". The code is in a separate thread, so i post here the thread code:

```
procedure TEco.Execute;

var
   contadoreco: Cardinal;
   buffer: string;

begin
     buffer:='12345678901234567890123456789012';
     eco:=TIdIcmpClient.Create(nil);
     for contadoreco:=1 to 4 do
         begin
              with eco do
                   begin
                        ReceiveTimeout:=2000;
                        Host:=servidor;
                        PacketSize:=32;
                        Ping(buffer,contadoreco);
                        ipservidor:=ReplyStatus.FromIpAddress;
                   end;
              Synchronize(procedure
                          begin
                               Form1.StringGrid1.Cells[0,contadoreco]:=ipservidor;
                               Form1.StringGrid1.Cells[1,contadoreco]:=IntToStr(tiempoeco);
                          end);
         end;
     eco.Free;
end;
```

The TEco object is declared here:

```
TEco = class(TThread)
           private
                  servidor: string;
                  eco: TIdIcmpClient;
                  terminado: Boolean;
                  tiempoeco: Cardinal;
                  ipservidor: string;
           protected
                    procedure Execute; override;
    end;
```

How i can ping a server with TidIcmpClient in Android? Am i doing something wrong? Superuser rights or some so? Thanks in advance for help me, and sorry for poor english. I expect you understand my question ;) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdIcmpClient` uses a RAW socket, which requires admin/root access on most systems, including Android.

There are two ways to perform a ping in Android using Android's own APIs:

1. use the `isReachable()` method of the [`InetAddress`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html) class.  However, apparently this [does not work correctly](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20106).
2. Use [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to spawn `/system/bin/ping`. In fact, the [`java.lang.Process`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html) documentation shows an example of that.  The downside is that you would have to manually parse the output.

Either solution would require you to use Delphi's JNI wrapper to access the relevant Android APIs.

Comment: Thanks Remy :) I will try both solutions and i will comment the results here.
Thank you very much Remy :) I appreciate your help a lot :)

Comment: I want to do one more question. If i use the posix functions (spawn, for example) and i read de STDOUT stream... I suppose that i will be doing the same as java.lang.processbuilder(), or not?
I do the question, because delphi xe6 has the posix libs, and it could be very insteresting use them (more easy than jni).
Thank you in advance again :)